# Short proof that $X^2 = X \Rightarrow X^{100} = X$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that a matrix $X$ satisfies $X^2 = X$ it is clear that $X^{100}=X$ by repeated multiplication of $X$. Algebraically, we might write:

$$X^{100} = (X^2)^{50}=X^{50}=(X^2)^{25}=X^{25}=X(X^2)^{12} = \dots = (X^2)^2 = X $$

But this seems like too much work for such a simple fact. Is there a short algebraic proof?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's easier to just prove that $X^n = X$ by induction; if $n = 1$, this is clear. Else, assume that the result is true for some $n \geq 1$ and conclude that

$$X^{n + 1} = X^{n} X = X X = X^2 = X$$

as desired.

Comment: you know, comparing our equations, there's really only one way to say certain things! ;)

Comment: @RobertLewis Pretty much, but yours was certainly more enthusiastic :)

Comment: yeah, well, I get that way sometimes! ;)

Comment: You should start the induction at $n\ge 2$. Otherwise the last equation $X^2=X$ is not necessarily true.

Comment: @vinnief The last equation is true by assumptions regarding $X$, not $n$.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$X^{n+2}=X^n\cdot X^2=X^n\cdot X=X^{n+1}$$

Now, if we have $f(n+1)=f(n),$ we can directly say $f(n+1)=f(1)$ for $n\ge0$

Answer (score 3):

Well, since $X^2 = X$, i.e., $X$ is idempotent, the standard inductive proof for idempotents in *any* ring works:  the inductive hypothesis is $X^k = X$, whence $X^{k + 1} = XX^k = XX = X^2 = X$.  Take $X^2 = X$ the base case and we're done, we have $X^n = X$ whether $n = 10$, 
$n = 10^6$, or $n$ is one-gazillion or even *more*!  What fun!  Cheers!

Comment: I suppose this is the right way to go about things. However, I still consider this to be a "long" algebraic proof as we are essentially arguing that $X^2=X \Rightarrow X^3 = X \Rightarrow X^4 = X \Rightarrow \dots \Rightarrow X^{100} = X$.